# c# filter listbox with textbox

Tags: c#, filter, listbox

I need a way to filter variable name of a list, I want to update the filter as fast as i write in the textbox. and add the game to forms Listbox.

structure of list is:

```
public class Games
{
    public string ID;
    public string Name;
    public string Password;
}
```

here's my code so far:

```
    List<Games> games = new List<Games>();
    private void textBox10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        d2ngList.Items.Clear();
        foreach(Games game in games)
        {
            //Filter List
            d2ngList.Items.Add(game.Name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! This site helps solving issues with your code. You should post your code here when you have results which are different from expected, or when you get an error. You also should describe **what results you have and what is expected and/or provide error details**. After that community will help you to solve issues and (sometimes) it'll give you some guidance. That is how stackoverflow works. As you can see, your question doesn't have all appropriate information. Please **edit** your question and other required information if you want to get some help.

Comment: And what is your problem ?

Comment: reframe your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out a solutin

```
    private void textBox10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        d2ngList.Items.Clear();
        foreach(Games game in HandlerClass.Instance.Games)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox10.Text))
            {
                if (game.Name.Contains(textBox10.Text))
                    d2ngList.Items.Add(game.Name);
            }
            else
                d2ngList.Items.Add(game.Name);
        }
       // games.Where(item => filterList.Contains(item));
    }
```

Comment: `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox10.Text))` is useless. filter value cannot be null. And if its empty, then `game.Name.Contains(textBox10.Text)` will always be true. You hate LINQ for some reason?

Comment: well i used LINQ in the end any way

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any filtering in your code, so maybe its your problem. You can use LINQ to filter games by name:

```
private void textBox10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filter = textBox10.Text;
    d2ngList.Items.Clear();
    foreach(Games game in games.Where(g => g.Name.Contains(filter)))
    {
        d2ngList.Items.Add(game.Name);
    }
}
```

Also you can optimize your code with `AddRange` method:

```
    string filter = textBox10.Text;
    d2ngList.Items.Clear();
    string[] names = games
        .Where(g => g.Name.Contains(filter)).Select(g => g.Name).ToArray();
    d2ngList.Items.AddRange(names);
```